Build Error with react-scripts in Drone CI/CD Pipeline
I'm experiencing an issue with my Drone CI/CD pipeline where the npm run build command fails with the following error:
> admin@0.1.0 build /drone/src
> react-scripts build  

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! admin@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the admin@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-09-11T01_33_45_340Z-debug.log

Here's a brief overview of my setup:
Drone YAML Configuration:
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

steps:
  - name: install
    image: node:14
    commands:
      - npm install

  - name: build
    image: node:14
    commands:
      - npm run build

  - name: deploy
    image: appleboy/drone-scp
    settings:
      host: 167.172.70.119
      username: forge
      port: 22
      target: /home/forge/dev.mls.taksu.tech
      source: ./build/*
      rm: true
      key:
        from_secret: forge_private_key

trigger:
  branch:
    - master

File Structure:
The project is located in /drone/src.
Local Build:
The npm run build command works perfectly on my local machine.
I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:
Cleaning npm cache using npm cache clean --force.
Ensuring all dependencies are correctly installed.
Comparing environment configurations between local and CI/CD.
Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this issue or suggest additional steps to diagnose and fix the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
